# How can I create an object with dynamically provided key-value pairs so TypeScript's `exactOptionalPropertyTypes = true` check passes?

Tags: javascript, typescript, interface

Typescript 4.4 [introduced](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-4/) `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` within the `strict` suite of type checking options:

> In JavaScript, reading a missing property on an object produces the
> value undefined. It’s also possible to have an actual property with
> the value undefined. A lot of code in JavaScript tends to treat these
> situations the same way, and so initially TypeScript just interpreted
> every optional property as if a user had written undefined in the
> type. For example,
>
> ```
> interface Person {
>     name: string,
>     age?: number;
> }
> ```
>
> was considered equivalent to
>
> ```
> interface Person {
>     name: string,
>     age?: number | undefined;
> }
> ```
>
> What this meant is that a user could explicitly write undefined in
> place of age.
>
> ```
> const p: Person = {
>     name: "Daniel",
>     age: undefined, // This is okay by default.
> };
> ```
>
> So by default, TypeScript doesn’t distinguish between a present
> property with the value undefined and a missing property. While this
> works most of the time, not all code in JavaScript makes the same
> assumptions. Functions and operators like Object.assign, Object.keys,
> object spread ({ ...obj }), and for–in loops behave differently
> depending on whether or not a property actually exists on an object.
> In the case of our Person example, this could potentially lead to
> runtime errors if the age property was observed in a context where its
> presence was important. In TypeScript 4.4, the new flag
> --exactOptionalPropertyTypes specifies that optional property types should be interpreted exactly as written, meaning that | undefined is
> not added to the type:
>
> ```
> // With 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes' on:
> const p: Person = {
>     name: "Daniel",
>     age: undefined, // Error! undefined isn't a number
> };
> ```
>
> This flag is not part of the --strict family and needs to be turned on
> explicitly if you’d like this behavior. It also requires
> --strictNullChecks to be enabled as well. We’ll be making updates to DefinitelyTyped and other definitions to try to make the transition as
> straightforward as possible, but you may encounter some friction with
> this depending on how your code is structured.

If this feature flag is enabled, my code

```
function f(input: OptionsInterface): void {
  const target: PacketInterface = {
    cmd: 'connect',
    clientId: input.clientId,
    protocolVersion: input.protocolVersion,
  };
  console.log(target);
};
```

gives an error:

```
Type '{ cmd: "connect"; clientId: string; protocolVersion: 4 | 5 | 3 | undefined }' is not assignable to type 'PacketInterface' with 'exactOptionalPropertyTypes: true'. Consider adding 'undefined' to the types of the target's properties.
  Types of property 'protocolVersion' are incompatible.
    Type '4 | 5 | 3 | undefined' is not assignable to type '4 | 5 | 3'.
```

The 'target' interface is PacketInterface:

```
export interface PacketInterface {
  cmd: 'connect'
  clientId: string
  protocolVersion?: 4 | 5 | 3
}
```

And the interface of the provided object is a superset of the `PacketInterface:

```
export interface OptionsInterface {
  cmd: 'connect'
  clientId: string
  protocolVersion?: 4 | 5 | 3
  clean?: boolean
  keepalive?: number
  username?: string
  password?: Buffer
}
```

I've created MCVE to demonstrate this: [TS Playground MCVE](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.4.4#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhgezcg3gKGf5ADwH4AuZAZzClAHMBuPAgTzORAFcBbAI2kYLIAXm069%20OAL44coSLEQoecKNib4S5KjRAMpMmBxAIwwNCFQAKUAAcOYcujQBKcgDc0wACZrBCc1TCGFzkyqoAvL6CBADkhDHktvYAdITqyJICBP4gFGgANhDJ%20Wi0lkLBzoyZQA).

I have a superset 'options' object that provides values to the subset 'packet' object that is based on a dependency's interface. In the 'packet' interface optional values use the `?:`, meaning if I provide `undefined` as a value TypeScript now complains.

While the error is expected, the solution is unclear. Updating the dependency's types is currently not possible. I can just disable the `exactOptionalPropertyTypes` feature flag for the error to go away, but that removes a level of type checking. How should I create the object with undefined values when this feature flag is enabled? Type coercion? Somehow using the interface to check for values in the `options` object? I do not want to manually check each value within the 'options' object to see if it exists before adding it to the 'packet' type object I am creating.

Comment: Please post (the part of) your code that tsc complains about

Comment: sure thing. updating.

Comment: "*meaning if I provide `undefined` as a value TypeScript now complains*" - that seems expected. Just don't provide the property at all? Please show us the code of the assignment that doesn't work, as a [mcve], maybe with a demo on the [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play)?

Comment: @Bergi I'll create the MCVE. It's not that it's unexpected, everything makes sense. The two solutions to fix my issue are: disable the feature flag in tsconfig, or rewrite my code in a way that is compatible.

Comment: And I suppose you're asking us *how* to rewrite your so that it becomes compatible? We can't answer that without the code itself.

Comment: `const target = input` or `const target = {...input}` should both work. If you want to omit the superfluous properties, it's a bit more complicated; you might do with rest syntax destructuring of the function parameter

Comment: @Bergi pardon my ignorance. I'm omitting the superfluous properties because it seems cleaner and less undefined than providing the whole object. Is this true though? Is there really any gain to omitting the superfluous properties?

Comment: It is cleaner and will lead to less surprises and better compatibility, but I'd say it depends on how much effort the cloning is and how the target object is actually used. Typescript actually always assumes that an object may have more properties than the ones declared by its type; it will matter when you try to enumerate them.

Answer (score 2):

You have to have the key as not defined. So you could use a ternary or a spread operator :

```
interface foo {
    x?: string;
    y?: number;
    z?: number;
}

interface bar {
    x?: string;
}

function f(input: foo): void {
    const zoom: bar = input.x ? { 'x': input.x } : {};
    /// or
    const zoom: bar = { ...input }

    console.log(zoom);
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&ts=4.4.4&ssl=12&ssc=34&pln=13&pc=21#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAhgezcg3gKGf5ADwH4AuZAZzClAHMBuPAgTzORAFcBbAI2kYLIAXm069+OAL44coSLEQoecKNib4S5KjRAMpMmBxAIwwNCFQAKUAAcOYcujQBKcgDc0wACZrBCc1TCGFzkyqoAvMi29gB0hMjEvoIEAOSEKeTRYHHqyJLI5FiSAgT+IIFCwQBMoSrIkVjIMc1ZebllFGgANhAxXWi0lpVoXM6MxUA)